# How to return an array from a function with the same name as that of the function in system verilog?

Tags: system-verilog

```
 module rev_array;

   int array_in[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

   typedef integer array[9:0];

   function array reverse(int array_in[10]);
     for(int j=$size(array_in)-1,int i=0;j>=0;j--,i++)
       begin     
         reverse[j]=array_in[i];
       end

     // working for(integer k=0;k<$size(array_in)-1;k++)
     // working   $display("reverse[%0d]:%0d", k, reverse[k]); 
     $display("inside function");             

   endfunction:reverse

   initial
     begin
       reverse(array_in);
       for(integer k=0;k<$size(array_in)-1;k++)
         begin
           $display("reverse[%0d]:%0d", k, reverse[k]);      
         end  
     end

 endmodule
```

> Error-[IUS] Illegal use of scope
>        testbench.sv, 22
>        rev_array, "rev_array.reverse"
>        Scope cannot be used in this context
>
> Error-[XMRIBS] Illegal bit select
>        testbench.sv, 22
>        Error is found in following cross-module reference, illegal bit select on 
>         the target.
>         Source info: $display("reverse[%0d]:%0d", k, rev_array.reverse[k]);

I am trying to reverse an array and return it in system verilog function, I  am able to see the reversed array inside the function by printing it but 
when I try to print it using $display outside the function, I think it is 
not being returned properly somehow, in the 4th line from end, getting 
errorError-[IUS]

Answer (score 1):

your both issues are related to the line where you use `reverse` function name as an array within $display.

```
$display("reverse[%0d]:%0d", k, reverse[k]); 
--------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

this is an illegal syntax causing both messages.

your initial block should look like the following.

```
initial
begin
    array result;
    result = reverse(array_in);
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^//
    for(integer k=0;k<$size(array_in)-1;k++)
    begin
      $display("reverse[%0d]:%0d", k, result[k]);
                                   // ^^^^^^ //      
    end  
end
```

call the function and use returned results for display.